# global static variable to be accessed in comment.tpl.php, node.tpl.php and in page.tpl.php

Tags: theming, comments

I wanted to show some ads inside the content (node, comments) and body.
I decided to add them using the template by adding some lines to comment.tpl.php, node.tpl.php and page.tpl.php

for example in comment.tpl.php I have:

```
print render($content);
if($id%3 == 1){
  echo "<iframe width='720' height='80' src='#####'></iframe>";
}
```

**I think this is a good way of adding ads**

Now that the ad code is repeated in these 3 files, I want to use a Global static variable so that the ad code can be placed in one place and can be access from these 3 tpl.php files

Can somebody please point me how to do it? Or an alternative Method of achieving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preprocess functions](https://drupal.org/node/223430) to add template variables in Drupal.

For example, you could use a generic preprocess function like

[`hook_preprocess`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7)

And add your variable there.

It will then be available in all the other template files.

Comment: I added `function bartik_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {$variables['my_var']="my_var_val"}` to template.php. And now it is available in tpl.php files as $my_var. Thanks a lot @David Thomas